# Displaying a node in a block withouth having the entire page render

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a Block... and am displaying a node (loading a node in it).

```
function my_module_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['my-block-id'] = array(
    'info' => t('Block Name'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function my_module_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my-block-id':
      $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
      $block['content'] = my_module_contents();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function my_module_contents() {
  return 'iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://localhost/try/node/27" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen /iframe';
}
```

As am using iframe so it renders all the content on the page but I want to display only the NODE Content in block, I don't want the header, menu, and footer to appear in the block.

Below is the image, thanks

[image]

Update :

If I implement node_view as per below code the node does get rendered as a full node but this only works if your block is on a node if the block is on another path say admin/structure/nodequeue then it does not work. So how can I make this work on such a path ? Pls help

```
function my_module_contents() {
 return drupal_render(node_view(node_load(27), 'full'));
}
```

**FINAL SOLVED SOLUTION ***

Below is the code which worked. Thank you laxman for your help

```
function customvishal_block_info() {
 $blocks = array();
 $blocks['my-block-id'] = array(
'info' => t('Block Name'),
 );
 return $blocks;
 }

 function customvishal_block_view($delta='') {
 $block = array();
 switch ($delta) {
  case 'my-block-id':
  $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
  $block['content'] = my_module_contents();
  break;
  }
  return $block;
  }

 function my_module_contents() {
 $customvishalfull= drupal_render(node_view(node_load(155), 'full'));

 // print_r($customvishalfull);
 // Example of creating and calling "strike" theme function.
 $output .= '<h2>Custom "strike" theme function</h2>';
 $output .= theme('customvishal_strike', array('string' =>$customvishalfull));


 return $output;

 }





function customvishal_theme() {
 return array(
 'customvishal_strike' => array(
  'variables' => array('string' => array()),
    'template' => 'property',
 ),
 ); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the iframe, it will load the entire page as you have experienced.  Consider using [`drupal_render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7), and [`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) to display only the node information.  You 
could change `my_module_contents()` to:

```
function my_module_contents() {
  return drupal_render(node_view(node_load(27), 'full'));
}
```

You could also change 'full' to 'teaser' to show the teaser of the node.

Comment: your tip got me half way . I can am now able to load it as you mentioned it but I loose the special formating which I want which I have created in my node-customtype.tpl Is there a way I can get this ?

Comment: I have updated my question. It working perfectly fine on a node page but when I use admin/structure/nodequeue its not working . cheers

Comment: Consider using [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) to theme your content. (see the comments for an example)

Comment: I read it and will try to implement it. I had created my own node-customtype.tpl to theme it so now if I use hook_theme() can I use this layout ? Wanted to know before I tried it out . thank you

Comment: You should be able to if you put that template name in for the template key